# Many to many Entity Framework Core how to insert

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, many-to-many

Based on the tutorial from MS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

This is how we define Post and Tag which have many-many relationship to each other:

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public string TagId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the database-update, it has been able to generate three tables: `Post`, `Tag` and `PostTag` which have the primary key `[PostId, TagId]`. Overall, the database schema is exactly what I thought.

However, what not mentioned is how to insert a `Post` with relationship with `Tags` or vice versa.

```
db.Posts.Add(new Post { Title="Title1", Content="Content1"});
db.Posts.Add(new Post { Title="Title2", Content="Content2"});
db.Tags.Add(new Tag { TagId="Tag1"});
db.Tags.Add(new Tag { TagId="Tag2"});
db.SaveChanges();
```

Now the database has 2 records in each table. My question is how can we add a new post that has tag1 and tag2? My code below doesn't work. Can someone point out what was wrong? Or do I need to do the old way by adding a third entity `PostTag`?

This is my code:

```
ICollection<Tag> tags = new List<Tag> {db.Tags.FirstOrDefault(i => i.TagId="Tag1"), db.Tags.FirstOrDefault(i => i.TagId="Tag2")};
db.Posts.Add(new Post { Title="Title3", Content="Content3", Tags=tags});

db.SaveChanges();
```

What I got is the exception saying it cannot insert post3 to the database.

Updated: Thanks for everyone's help. Found out that I made a mistake in my real code. This is my actual code:

```
vICollection<Tag> tags = new List<Tag> {db.Tags.FirstOrDefault(i => i.TagId="Tag1"), db.Tags.FirstOrDefault(i => i.TagId="Tag2")};
var post3 = new Post { Title="Title3", Content="Content3"};
db.Posts.Add(post3);
post3.Tags = tags; // wrong position, should be called before db.Posts.Add(post3)
db.SaveChanges();
```

The mistake is `post3.Tags = tags;` is called after `db.Posts.Add(post3);`. It should be like this:

```
vICollection<Tag> tags = new List<Tag> {db.Tags.FirstOrDefault(i => i.TagId="Tag1"), db.Tags.FirstOrDefault(i => i.TagId="Tag2")};
var post3 = new Post { Title="Title3", Content="Content3"};
post3.Tags = tags; // correct position
db.Posts.Add(post3);
db.SaveChanges();
```

I have also removed PostId from my code.

Comment: You should iterate through your ICollection tags

Comment: Define/explain "doesn't work". Because the code as shown is ok.

Comment: Hi @tala999,What is the error message?and no need to specify the PostId when you create a new Post.Also,what is the version of your ef core?

Comment: Don't state the error message in your narration. Post the actual error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add the `Post` with specifying the `PostId`,it will get the following error:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Posts' when
> IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Just remove the `PostId` and the code will work fine:

```
ICollection<Tag> tags = new List<Tag> {
           db.Tags.FirstOrDefault(i => i.TagId="Tag1"), 
           db.Tags.FirstOrDefault(i => i.TagId="Tag2")};
db.Posts.Add(new Post { Title="Title3", Content="Content3", Tags=tags});

db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Rena already mentioned, your code is failing to work because you are setting primary-key value (`PostId=3`) while creating the `Post` entity. I'll just add an improvement point.

In the code below, you are doing multiple trip to the database to fetch one `Tag` at a time -

```
ICollection<Tag> tags = new List<Tag> {db.Tags.FirstOrDefault(i => i.TagId="Tag1"), db.Tags.FirstOrDefault(i => i.TagId="Tag2")};
```

You could just fetch the list of tags in one go, like -

```
var tags = db.Tags.ToList();
```

and your final code might look like -

```
var tags = db.Tags.ToList();
var post = new Post
{
    Title = "Title3",
    Content = "Content3",
    Tags = tags.Where.(i => i.TagId == "Tag1" || i.TagId == "Tag2")).ToList()
}
db.Posts.Add(post);
db.SaveChanges()
```

Comment: Of course, if tags has a lot of entries, then your line `var tags = db.Tags.ToList()` would be horrendously expensive.
Wouldn't it be better to put the where clause here so that the database is doing the querying rather than doing it in memory?